# How to use VoIP to call a distant conventional telephone from my computer?

Tags: .net, voip

I am having my webpage where i am entering the telephone number of the person i am trying to call. So what's next to reach them through VoIP? How to reach the network provider for call processing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use twilio api or asterisk and develop your api

Anyway you need voip2pstn gate or provider